# Connecting button to create and store an object in Qt C++

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qapplication

I am creating a Qt Widget based app and I want to be able to add objects to std::list<>(that store objects of some class) at runtime by using button(QPushButton).
Is there any way to pass this list by reference so I can store created objects in it?

AFAIK there is no way to use connect(Object1, signal, Object2, slot), because slot can't have any parameters.

If I can't do this the way I explained how can I achieve it?

Comment: *"slot can't have any parameters"* -- Where did you hear that? That's not true at all.

Comment: I use slots with parameters all the time. With that said it may be some work connecting a signal to that does not have a parameter to a slot with parameters. Depending on the situation you may use several different methods to make it work.

Comment: You can `connect` to a [`lambda`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html#signals-and-slots-with-default-arguments) with captures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without more context it's difficult to know exactly what you're trying to achieve but... given a variable `objects` defined as follows...

```
std::list<QObject *> objects;
```

You can connect a button's `clicked` signal to a `lambda` that captures `objects` by reference with...

```
QObject::connect(&button, &QPushButton::clicked,
                 [&objects](bool checked)
                 {

                     /*
                      * Update objects here.
                      */
                 });
```

Comment: thank you very much :) That was exactly what I was hoping for